# Format X axis Label of Highcharts

Tags: highcharts

I have developed the Highcharts label as much as possible but not able to format as required

https://jsfiddle.net/5ug4wpbz/1/

Please tell me how to format the date and time as shown in the image attached with this.

Expected :

```
https://ibb.co/WV638L4
```

Comment: There are any tooltip in the image and where is your current code ?

Comment: @Core972 i have added my code in jsfiddle for your reference. Please tell me solution for it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can not use `category` and `datetime` axis type together, these are two mutually exclusive values. However, you can achieve the wanted result by using one of them.

For `category` axis type set `pointPlacement` to `'between'` and `xAxis.labels.align` to `'left'`:

```
xAxis: {
    categories: [...],
    labels: {
        align: 'left'
    }
},
series: [{
    pointPlacement: 'between',
    data: [...]
}]
```

**Live demo:** https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/fnsuxt90/

---

For `datetime` axis type, you need to use `x` and `y` data values or set `pointStart` and `pointInterval` properties:

```
xAxis: {
    type: 'datetime'
},
series: [{
    pointStart: 1563040800,
    pointInterval: 1000 * 60 * 30,
    data: [...]
}]
```

**Live demo:** https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/f1c59a0w/

---

**API Reference:**

https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/series.line.label

https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/series.line.pointPlacement

https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/series.line.type

---

**EDIT:**

To split the label into two lines, inset `<br>` tag to a string in `labels.formatter` function:

```
xAxis: {
    ...,
    labels: {
        formatter: function() {
            return this.value.split(' ').join('<br>')
        }
    }
}
```

**Live demo:** https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/vgp46bhw/

Comment: Thanks for your quick answer
But still i think i did not get my solution (as mentioned in the image)

The date has to come in first line and time has to come in second line
if Possible please tell me the solution for this

Comment: Hi @Kishore Kumar, I have edited my answer, please check the result.

Comment: This is the perfect solution. Thanks for the help